# what is the difference in pandas syntax to reference an element?

Tags: python, database, pandas

For a pandas dataframe, why are these two syntax' different, and what exactly is the second returning?

```
df.iloc[0]['data']
137

df.iloc[0].data
<memory at 0x1c4d7e948>
```

Comment: Can you share your sample DataFrame?

Comment: It is explained in the docs, as well as the link above.